# List of Points taken from a moving Object

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, opencv, append

I am having some trouble accessing a list of stored x,y coordinates from the center of a block that moves across the screen. I have been able to successfully get the x and y coordinate of the block for each frame but am having trouble storing this information and then being able to access the point at certain stages.
My aim is to be able to join the points together to form a trail.
Below what i currently have.

Class definition:

```
    class People:

        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 0
            self.y = 0
```

assume that at each point that the center is detected, cX and cY is updated correctly.

```
    MultPeople=[]
```

The following falls inside the loop that goes through the video frame by frame

```
    Person=People()
    Person.x=cX
    Person.y=cY
    MultPeople.append(Person)
```

but now when i want to access these points sequentially to join the dots, i am only able to get them one at a time and am therefore not able to.

```
    for index,man in enumerate(MultPeople):
        print (index,man.x,man.y)
        xplot=man.x
        yplot=man.y
        cv2.circle(frame1, (xplot, yplot), 2, [50, 20, 255], 3)
```

this successfully draws a circle onto the original image at the centre point, but the answer is given back like this

```
    (0, 306, 379)
    (0, 307, 377)
    (0, 307, 384)
    (0, 305, 396)
    (0, 309, 409)
    (0, 310, 431)
```

what needs to be added in order to get a value for the index, i am assuming that this would be needed in order to access certain points.

I also entered the following line after printing the index,man.x,man.y

```
        print np.size(MultPeople)
```

and it prints back 1 each time, I am thinking the issue is therefore with the append function as it is not adding a new value to the list each time, but am not sure how this should be corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post all the code from the updating loop to the printing loop without breaks, "as is",  because it is hard to see the problem like this. But from what I see - you possibly have your list created, updated and printed inside the updating loop, like this:

```
while condition:
    MultPeople=[]
    Person=People()
    # Here you somehow get the new cX and cY values
    Person.x=cX
    Person.y=cY
    MultPeople.append(Person)
    for index,man in enumerate(MultPeople):
        print (index,man.x,man.y)
        xplot=man.x
        yplot=man.y
        cv2.circle(frame1, (xplot, yplot), 2, [50, 20, 255], 3)
```

So the list `MultPeople` is created, appended one item, then the `for` loop goes over the list with one item (i.e. it is executed only once, with the `index == 0` and `size` of `1`) and you receive the result you have.

That is, if my guess is right. You should really post the code as-is, it's really hard reading it chopped in pieces.

If that's the case what you actually want is:

```
MultPeople=[]
while condition:
    Person=People()
    # Here you somehow get the new cX and cY values
    Person.x=cX
    Person.y=cY
    MultPeople.append(Person)
for index,man in enumerate(MultPeople):
    print (index,man.x,man.y)
    xplot=man.x
    yplot=man.y
    cv2.circle(frame1, (xplot, yplot), 2, [50, 20, 255], 3)
```

Comment: Thank you, moving the declaration outside the while loop fixed the problem. Apologies, Will post full code in future question